# Extract only node-id of a particular node in Redis Cluster when using CLUSTER NODES command

Tags: shell, redis

I have a Redis Cluster running with 6 nodes on a Linux server. 
I need to delete one of the nodes from the cluster.
I am writing a shell script which deletes the node from the cluster.

Problem:

When I run CLUSTER NODES via redis-cli, I will get the information of all the nodes with different parameters like node-id and so on as an output. I just need to extract node-id of a particular node from the displayed output and use it in my script.

Help required!!!

Comment: It would be helpful for people who don't have Redis cluster installed if you attach a sample of the command's output (redacted if needed). Also, this isn't really a Redis-related question.

Answer (score 3):

Just run this command, with corresponding ip and port:

`./redis-cli -h 172.31.160.110 -p 7000 CLUSTER NODES | grep myself | cut -d" " -f1`

Output:

```
a415b9df6ce0c3c757ad4270242ae432147cacbb
```

See this tutorials: http://codeflex.co/configuring-redis-cluster-on-linux/

Answer (score 1):

Just log into the specified node you want to get it's **ID** by this command

```
redis-cli -h ip -p port
```

then type

```
CLUSTER MYID
```